# Google GeoCode Co-ordinate vary over a period of time

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, salesforce

I had geocoded around 40k address three months ago using google geocode api. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json

Due to limitation on the number of requests per day I had processed 2500 records every day.  Out of 40k records 10k records were processed with `location` type `APPROXIMATE`.

But today if I process the same 10k records again the `location` type is changed to `ROOFTOP` with a different `lat` and `long`.

There were no changes in the records which had ‘ROOFTOP’ and `RANGE_INTERPOLATED`
I.e. If I process any `ROOFTOP` record now – There is no change in `lat`, `long` and `location` type.

Couldn't understand why there is change in `APPROXIMATE` location type records.

Please guide me.

Thanks,
Indy

Answer (score 0):

1. it's not allowed to store these data for  more than 30 calendar days (https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_3)
2. APPROXIMATE means **APPROXIMATE** , it's fine when results become more precise

Answer (score 0):

Google states in their terms of use that the geocoded results can only be temporarily cached and need to be refreshed periodically (which implies to me they will change).  A change from APPROXIMATE to ROOFTOP sounds like they got more accurate.  That shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: geocodezip, Thanks for your reply. 
FYI I am not using any paid google key, hope this will not an issue.  Also could you please post the terms of use link that highlights temporary cache?    So I’ll show this to my client that  my code is not in-correct.
Thanks,
Indy